# Stata: Assign labels to range of variables with a loop

Tags: loops, stata, label

Let's say I have 60 variables, none with similar naming patterns. I want to assign labels to all variables, which I stored locally. So for example

```
local mylabels "dog cat bird"
```

However I am struggling with the exact expression of the loop. Do I have to store my variable range globally and then use a foreach? Or do I use forvalues?

**Edit:** I was referring to variable labels. I managed to create a loop, similar to the method used here http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/looping-over-parallel-lists/. However I ran into a more difficult problem: my variables have no particular naming patterns, and the labels have special characters (spaces, commas, %-signs), and here is where my loop does not work.

Some example data (excuse the randomness):

```
gen Apples_ts_sum = .
gen Pears_avg_1y = .
gen Bananas_max_2y = .
```

And some example labels:

"Time series of apples, sum, %" "Average of pears, over 1 year"
"Maximum of bananas, over 2 years".

I ran into this entry by Nick Cox: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-10/msg00285.html and tried to apply the mentioned parentheses method, like so:

```
 local mylabels `" "Time series of apples, sum, %" "Average of pears, over 1 year" "Maximum of bananas, over 2 years" "'
```

But could not get it to work.

Comment: Labels means value labels? variable labels? Probably the second, but if you do not show code a minimal expectation is that you show how you want your data to look.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that clarified this. In general, the approach of putting all the variable labels into one local macro poses the problem of taking them out again, as you discovered. It can be as easy to use `varm` interactively, or if you prefer more directly reproducible research to create a do-file defining the variable labels one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to label all the variables the same thing, for example `"dog cat bird"`, Then you can use the `varlist` option for the `describe` command. Let's say your 60 variables can be generally listed with the expression EXP. Then:

```
    qui des EXP, varlist
    foreach variable in `r(varlist)'{
        label var `variable' "dog cat bird"
    }
```

**Edited:**
Taking your example data, I created another local containing the variable names.

```
 local myvar `" "Apples_ts_sum" "Pears_avg_1y" "Bananas_max_2y" "'
 local mylabels `" "Time series of apples, sum, %" "Average of pears, over 1 year" "Maximum of bananas, over 2 years" "'
 forval n = 1/3{
    local a: word `n' of `mylabels'
    local b: word `n' of `myvar'
    di "variable `b', label `a'"
    label var `b' "`a'"
 }
```

Note that I manually created the list of variables. You can automatically create this list using the method I listed above, with `des, varlist`.

```
qui des , varlist
foreach var in `r(varlist)'{
    local myvar_t "`myvar_t' `var'"
}
```

You can then use the local `myvar_t` instead of `myvar` in the above example.

Comment: It seems most unlikely that the OP wants the same variable label for all variables. But if that is so, the `describe` is dispensable here, as `foreach var of var EXP` will suffice. However, OP has yet to clarify question.

Comment: This is true. If the label should be different for each variable, and there are no systematic similarities, then I cannot imagine something which is not manual.

Comment: I guess wildly that the OP has put lots of variable labels into a macro and now wants to take them out again, but speculation is futile; perhaps it's value labels after all. It's the OP's sole responsibility to make clear what is wanted.

Comment: Late reply here: see edit in original post for more info.

Comment: The edited reply is now helpful, and would be made even better by taking it out the first guess at what was meant.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not being clear at first. With your code I run into a similar problem as initially: the loop works for the first 3 variables, but then just doesn't apply labels anymore (no error message). The issue is probably with the `local mylabels` line, because the labels (which should normally be red as strings) are shown in black, words such as "sum" are highlighted like commands, and then somewhere in the middle the text is recognised as strings, until the end. I tried to isolate the issue (went through my (long) line of strings), but could not find any syntax errors.

Comment: @paraselene You should show us a reproducible example of something that doesn't work, meaning data and code. Otherwise the only comment might well be, "Sorry, but you must have made some small mistake". Alternatively, as hinted above in a comment on your original post, just don't do this. Use a do-file to define a set of variable labels. It is much, much quicker and easier to identify where something goes wrong.

Comment: Dear Nick, I cannot post anything reproducible, as I do not know where exactly the issue is, and how to reproduce that kind of error. I am currently already doing the labeling one by one in a do-file and it works, but I was keen on finding out how it can be expressed in a loop. Since I cannot reproduce the issue (for now), I will stick to the one-by-one labeling and thank you kindly for your help (I've learned more about looping in any case!).