# Assign value labels from external data dictionary in Stata

Tags: stata

I would like to `label` variable values using an already constructed data dictionary. 
A minimal dataset:

```
clear
input q1p0  q1p1    q2p0    q2p1    q2p2    q2p3
1   1   1   1   4   34
1   1   2   2   3   36
1   1   1   4   2   45
1   2   2   4   2   46
1   1   1   3   2   23
1   1   2   4   1   35
1   1   2   2   3   22
1   1   1   2   1   17
1   1   1   4   1   40
1   1   2   3   2   18
1   2   2   2   1   40
end
```

Naturally, by manually reading from the dictionary I would have done:

```
label define yesno 1 "Yes" 2 "No"
label values q1p0 q1p1 q2p0 yesno

label define workload 0 "No change" 1 "Very low workload" 2 "Low workload" 3 "More workload" 4 "A lot more workload" 98 "Don’t know"    
label values q2p1 q2p2 workload

label define yesnodont 1 "Yes" 2 "No" 98 "Don’t Know"   
label values q2p3 yesnodont
```

However, I have many variables that require labeling and so an automated approach using a loop would be helpful.
A minimal dictionary:

```
clear
input str4 variable  str20 valuelabel value
q1p0    "Yes"   1
q1p0    "No"    2
q1p1    "Yes"   1
q1p1    "No"    2
q2p0    "Yes"   1
q2p0    "No"    2
q2p1    "No change" 0
q2p1    "Very low workload" 1
q2p1    "Low workload"  2
q2p1    "More workload" 3
q2p1    "A lot more workload"   4
q2p1    "Don’t know"    98
q2p2    "No change" 0
q2p2    "Very low workload" 1
q2p2    "Low workload"  2
q2p2    "More workload" 3
q2p2    "A lot more workload"   4
q2p2    "Don’t know"    98
q2p3    "Yes"   1
q2p3    "No"    2
q2p3    "Don't know"    98
end
```

The variables in the data set above represent the `variable` to be named, the `valuelabel` to assign to a particular category of the `variable` and the `value` of the `variable` category.

How could one automate the process?

I need to generate:

```
clear
input str4 variable  strL labelstatement
q1p0    `"1 "Yes" 2 "No""'
q1p1    `"1 "Yes" 2 "No""'      
q2p0    `"1 "Increased" 2 "Decreased" 3 "No change" 98 "Don’t know""'   
q2p1    `"0 "No change" 1 "Very low workload" 2 "Low workload" 3 "More workload" 4 "A lot more workload" 98 "Don’t know""'  
q2p2    `"0 "No change" 1 "Very low workload" 2 "Low workload" 3 "More workload" 4 "A lot more workload" 98 "Don’t know""'  
q2p3    `"1 "Yes" 2 "No" 98 "Don’t Know""'      
end
```

A related question has been posted before but that one involved labeling variables and not values.
[Stata: Assign labels to range of variables with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276891/stata-assign-labels-to-range-of-variables-with-a-loop)

In R I could do this:
First create the minimal dictionary:

```
library(dplyr)

valuelabels <- read.table(text="variable valuelabel value
q1p0                 'Yes'     1
q1p0                  'No'     2
q1p1                 'Yes'     1
q1p1                  'No'     2
q2p0                 'Yes'     1
q2p0                  'No'     2
q2p1           'No change'     0
q2p1  'Very low workload'     1
q2p1        'Low workload'     2
q2p1       'More workload'     3
q2p1 'A lot more workload'     4
q2p1          'Don\\'t know'    98
q2p2           'No change'     0
q2p2   'Very low workload'     1
q2p2        'Low workload'     2
q2p2       'More workload'     3
q2p2 'A lot more workload'     4
q2p2          'Don\\'t know'    98
q2p3                ' Yes'     1
q2p3                  'No'     2
q2p3          'Don\\'t know'    98", 
                 header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Now create the statements that will finally be executed as Stata code:

```
valuelabels <- valuelabels %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(labelstatement=paste(value,'"',valuelabel,'"', collapse=' ', sep=''),
         labelstatement= gsub('"',' "', labelstatement),
         labelstatement1=paste("label define",variable, labelstatement),
         labelstatement2=paste("label values",variable, variable)) %>%
  select(variable,labelstatement1,labelstatement2) %>%
  slice(1)
```

which gives:

```
variable    labelstatement1 labelstatement2
q1p0    label define q1p0 1 "Yes " 2 "No "  label values q1p0 q1p0
q1p1    label define q1p1 1 "Yes " 2 "No "  label values q1p1 q1p1
q2p0    label define q2p0 1 "Yes " 2 "No "  label values q2p0 q2p0
```

Comment: The question is morphing on each edit. That's entirely allowed, but it makes it difficult to follow. Two specific comments: 1. The last block of output isn't legal Stata code. I don't know if it is intended to be.  2. Same comment on the `concat()` block.

Comment: `concat()` block now removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a case of "I wouldn't start from there". But given that you have, suppose you read in those details as data. Then the single command

```
gen line = "label define " + variable + " " + string(value) + " " + char(34) + valuelabel + char(34) + ", modify"
```

would create a variable `line` with contents fit to be exported and executed as a do-file.

Here `char(34)` is the `"` character. There are other ways to ensure that literal quote marks get added, but that is fairly low risk.

Otherwise put, you have the ingredients there for a do-file. You just need to add some text and re-order.

You can mix instructions like this and real data, insofar as any text could go in a string variable. But it's a matter of style whether you do. (I'd usually reach for any favourite text editor.)

Comment: The question changed considerably while I was writing my answer. I am more puzzled by the question now. At some point writing Stata commands is essential, and doing it directly seems better than doing it indirectly. I may well miss what you are driving at.

Comment: The line of code you suggested above would work if all the contents required  to generate the variable line lie on the same line in the data set. But here it is required to pull some values from one line and 'paste' them into another line. That is why I was thinking of the `by` command. However, I am not sure if `by` and `foreach` work together. I could do that in R as in my edits above.

Comment: I don't follow your distinction. My code works on your data input to create the contents of a do-file. If you prefer to do it in R, that's fine by me but that was not your original question. I have no bias against R but my one-line solution (apart from export to a file) seems simpler than your R code. That doesn't mean that it would be easier to write if you were stronger in R.  I remain puzzled about your goals here.  `by` appears irrelevant to your problem and `foreach` appears unnecessary as the `generate` statement provides an automatic loop over the instructions `input` as data.

Comment: Your code works but does not give the desired output. It gives for example on the first row of the variable line
`label define q1p0 1 "Yes"` while the desired output is `label define q1p0 1 "Yes " 2 "No "`. The missing part being `2 "No "` which needs to be pulled from the second line and pasted into the first line. Actually, this is the most tricky part of the process. The R code was able to do that but I suppose it is possible also in Stata

Comment: Your desired output is not essential at all.  I draw your attention to the `, modify` added at the end of each command line in my original answer, which solves your problem completely.  See `help label` for this and other syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a dataset with labels in the way you presented them. First,
let's assume, to make it a bit easier to follow, that we are talking about
a country. Let's assume the country has 4 states, each with 4 districts, each with 4 towns.

This gives us 1 + 4 + 4^2 + 4^3 = 85 objects.

```
clear
set more off
set obs 85

gen name=""
replace name = "country" in 1
replace name = "state" in 2/5
replace name = "district" in 6/21
replace name = "town" in 22/85

bysort name: gen value = _n
gen label = name + strofreal(value)
```

Great! Now we have our label names, values and the labels themselves. Let's go ahead and save this as a .dta file to open later. You wanted to reference a .csv file, but its all the same. You would just need to use `import delimited` instead of `use` later on.

```
tempfile labels
save `labels'
```

*Note that you need to have this all in one .do file, since I am referencing temporary files. I would suggest copy/pasting this into a .do file rather than inputting it directly line-by-line.*

Now we need to create a sample dataset that would need labels, with the variables country, state, district, and town.

```
clear
set more off
set obs 1

foreach x in country state district town {
    gen `x' = _n
    expand 4
    sort `x'
}
duplicates drop town, force
```

Now, there is one unique country, 4 unique states, 16 unique districts, and 64 unique towns. They are all in terms of an integer variable with no current label.

Now we will create a loop that preserves this data, then references the temporary file with the labels we want for each variable-value.

```
foreach x in country state district town {
    tempfile `x'do                              
    preserve                                        
        use `labels', clear                             // Reference the "labels" tempfile we made earlier
        keep if name == "`x'"                           // Keep only the rows where name is the name of the label we want to define
        qui sum value                                   // Allows me to reference r(N) later, the number of rows in the dataset
        forvalues i = 1/`r(N)' {                        // Inner loop generates value/label pair for each unique value of x
            local value = value[`i']                    // Pulls out the value for row 1, 2, 3,... etc.
            local label = label[`i']                    // Pulls out the label string for row 1, 2, 3,.. etc.
            label define `x' `value' "`label'", add     // Define and continuously add to label definition each time it loops
        }                                               // End inner loop
        label save `x' using ``x'do', replace           // Saves label instructions in temporary do file so we can access it after "restore"
    restore
    do ``x'do'                                          // Re-create the labels in our main dataset (they were lost after "restore")
    label values `x' "`x'"                              // Apply label to values                                
}                                                       // End outer loop
```

And voila! Labels for each variable have been generated and applied. The answer seems long, but remember that we had to create mock-data first. The loop is all you actually need if you have your labels defined such that the "name" in the labels file is the same as the variable name you want to assign that value to.

Comment: Explaining another way to do it is always welcome, but this does seem like a lot of work compared with the short solution in my answer and it's highly specific to the dataset concerned.  Also, you (appear to) claim that nobody uses line-by-line  command input in Stata. That may be rhetorical exaggeration, but it's just incorrect. Line by line is often the best way to proceed, at least initially. Naturally, I have no objection to programming Stata too.

Comment: Definitely an exaggeration. Yours is definitely a quicker, though this solution was modified from a similar approach where I had a wide dataset instead of long (so variables countryid, country, stateid, state, etc.. Instead of keeping observations if name==x, you would keep variables xid and x. In this case, it was actually quicker than reshaping. But mostly it's just another approach with different tools.

Comment: Removed that line to avoid rubbing people the wrong way.